# Reading files with istreambuf_iterator vs copy_n

Tags: c++, stl, ifstream

I want to parse different kinds of chunks in a file with varying length, so I created a function to read out a chunk by passing in the ifstream, like this:

```cpp
void parse_next(std::ifstream& input_file, std::vector<uint8_t>& data, size_t count)
{
    std::copy_n(
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input_file),
        count,
        std::back_inserter(data)
    );
}
```

I expected the file position to increment *count*, i.e.,

```cpp
// some init code
size_t const pos_before{input_file.tellg()};
parse_next(input_file, data, count);
size_t const pos_after{input_file.tellg()};

// this assumption is _not_ correct! 
assert(count == (pos_after - pos_before)); 

// but this is!
assert((count - 1) == (pos_after - pos_before));
```

However, using the `input_file.read()` with *count* instead of `std::copy_n` gives the right count.

So what's going on here? I can't see anywhere in the documentation of istreambuf_iterator where this is mentioned.
Or is it the `std::copy_n` that is messing with me?

Note that in the example above, we can assume that there is plenty of data left to read, so it is not because the file is empty.
Further, the file is opened as *binary*.

Comment: Neither of the asserts work since they are missing a `)`. What is `data.size()` before and after?

Comment: ```data.size()``` is incremented by ```count``` (both with ```std::copy_n()``` and ```.read()```).
Fixed the missing assert ')'.

Comment: `parse_next` needs to accept the vector parameter by reference. Caused some minor confusion when trying this out. https://godbolt.org/z/jzb3co6Wx Interesting that the position is one less than you'd expect but also that reading more results in duplication. I don't know the answer to your question but it does make me happy I avoid writing code like that.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, forgot the reference to the data - it's in my more elaborate code. Here I just extracted the essentials.
How would you write this instead?

Comment: I would use `read`. If I was reading a fixed number of items I'd resize the vector and use one read, and if I didn't know how many I'd read one at a time and push_back until a read failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `istreambuf_iterator`.  It is an input-only iterator.  Imagine that you have a file with 5 bytes and you read `count=2`:

1. It calls [`sgetc`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/sgetc/) to read the first byte.  This does not advance the stream position.
2. Since `count=2`, `copy_n` needs one more byte.  So it increments the stream position.
3. It reads the second byte using `sgetc`.
4. Since `count=2`, no more byte are required.  `copy_n` returns.

Note that only step 2 increments the stream position, and it only needs to be called once when reading two characters.

Yes, this is strange.  But most people would just use `input_file.read()`.  I've almost never seen people use `istreambuf_iterator` in production code...not least of all because it is inefficient for your type of use case.

We could say hey, let's change `copy_n` to increment the iterator before returning.  That would fix this 0.1% use case, at the cost of slowing down other use cases.

Comment: So that's the key - the usage of ```sgetc``` under the hood. I really thought that ```std::copy_n``` would overload to ```memcpy``` or ```memmove````. But of course, with the back_inserter we might need to do some dynamic allocation along the way.
So that standard way for best performance is to do a resize() and then do a read into the std::vector (assuming I still want to use std::vector, which is probably my best option if I want to retain dynamic allocation), or do you have a better way?

Comment: It makes perfect sense explained like this and it's counterintuitive to me since I'd expect the actual read to advance the file pointer and not the iterator. When I do see folks using this sort of pattern it is usually to read the entire file so in that case it doesn't seem to matter either way. Thanks for teaching me something new. :)